# Using both original name and English name in a URL

Tags: url, keyword-stuffing

Let's say, I am adapting a URL structure like:

```
[domain]/neuschwanstein-castle-schloss-neuschwanstein
```

*Neuschwanstein Castle* is a castle in Germany and its original name is *Schloss Neuschwanstein* in German.

Is putting both the English name and the original name in a URL considered keyword stuffing?

Comment: Can you give an example of a URL with the English name? I would suspect this is not necessary. Google and Bing should figure it all out okay. As well, it is possible that this will be seen as manipulation. It may be better to put the English name somewhere prominent in your content.

Answer (score 1):

I won't consider it keyword stuffing for one reason:

According to Google [Irrelevant keywords](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358?hl=en):

> "Keyword stuffing" refers to the practice of loading a webpage with
>   keywords or numbers in an attempt to manipulate a site's ranking in
>   Google search results. Often these keywords appear in a list or group,
>   or out of context (not as natural prose).

The most important fact here is that your URL **is representing the content of your page**.

So as for an User Experience point of view, which is one of the most important topics in SE like Google, I wouldn't be surprised if the name of that castle also has the name of the castle in their original name.

If this is a good slug scheme or the content of the slug can be different is another story, but doesn't seems to be keyword stuffing at all.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the term 'neuschwanstein' twice in the URL as your example shows is not necessary. What would be the main language for the on-page copy be, English or German?

Comment: The language of the page will be English.

Answer (score 0):

> Duplicate content is content that appears on the Internet in more than
>   one place (URL).

https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose that your content is:

1) Five pages of totally new and original material that makes you a niche topic authority on your subject.
2) That the terms in German and English are actually interchangeable.

So you might want: [domain]/neuschwanstein-schloss/castle/index.html